# difference between <> and () they both look like typecasting

Tags: c#, .net

I'm going through a .NET Core tutorial and I'm seeing a lot things like `ILogger<HomeController>` which to me (since all I recognize them as types) looks a lot like typecasting.

The only conclusion I can come up with is if I wrote say `ILogger(HomeController)` I'm telling it to cast it to say type `HomeController` (giving me an error because I cannot) while `ILogger<HomeController>` is just telling the controller 'which' type of `ILogger` it is.

However, I am having trouble finding any documentation so my conclusions can be totally wrong.......

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, `<>` is used for **generic types**. `ILogger<HomeController>` is a type itself. `()` is used to **cast**: that can be to a generic type, but also to a primitive type or a non-generic one

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer if you gave a concrete piece of code

Comment: Thank you, this is a duplicate. This is the first I heard of generics in C#, so I didn't know exactly how to ask the question!